# Welche Präposition verlangt "Hinweise haben"?

Tags: preposition, sentence-structure

In folgendem Zusammenhang kann man schreiben:

> 1. Wir haben keine Hinweise **auf** eine Manipulation unserer Daten.

Der folgende Satz ist zwar verständlich, nachdem aber das Verb *hinweisen* die Präposition *auf* verlangt, ist er wahrscheinlich nicht korrekt:

> 2. Wir haben keine Hinweise **für** eine Manipulation unserer Daten.

Wenn man nun aber den Satzbau umstellt, ergibt sich Folgendes:

> 1. **Auf** eine Manipulation unserer Daten haben wir keine Hinweise.

Ich meine, dass dies nicht richtig ist, denn spontan würde ich sagen:

> 2. **Für** eine Manipulation unserer Daten haben wir keine Hinweise.

Wie kommt es hier zu einer Änderung der Präposition? Gibt es noch andere Beispiele, in denen der Satzbau die Präposition verändern kann?

Oder liegt mein Sprachgefühl hier falsch und man sollte immer *auf* mit *Hinweis* benutzen?

Comment: Ich musste an den Satz "Es gibt keine Hinweise auf den Täter" denken. [Google verrät bei der Suche nach "den täter gibt es keine hinweise"](https://www.google.de/search?q=%22den+t%C3%A4ter+gibt+es+keine+hinweise%22&num=20&filter=0&biw=1472&bih=880), dass der Satz ausschließlich mit "Auf" begonnen wird, allerdings sind das auch nur eine handvoll Ergebnisse

Comment: 3. _**Zu** einer Manipulation unserer Daten haben wir keine Hinweise._ Ich habe keine Antwort, aber einen Denkanstoß: Es gibt _hinauf_ und _hinzu_, aber nicht _*hinfür_.

Comment: @Crissov: kann man dann auch sagen: *Wir haben keine Hinweise **zu** einer Manipulation unserer Daten?* - das klingt schräg, während Dein Vorschlag oben in schon in Ordnung ist.

Comment: Nur „auf“ ist richtig.

Comment: Ok, unten würde ich davon überzeugt, dass das nur für mich gilt.

Answer (score 2):

Der Satz

> Wir haben keine Hinweise für eine Manipulation unserer Daten.

ist korrekt, was man spätestens an der Umformulierung erkennt:

> Wir haben keine Hinweise dafür, dass unsere Daten manipuliert wären.

Siehe auch [den Duden-Eintrag zu Hinweis](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Hinweis).

(Auch der Satz

> Wir haben keine Hinweise zur Manipulation unserer Daten.

ist grammatikalisch korrekt, nur geht die Bedeutung stärker in eine andere Richtung: **zur** hat hier eher finalen Charackter: **zum Zwecke der Manipulation**.)

Dass der Satz

> Auf eine Manipulation unserer Daten haben wir keine Hinweise.

falsch klingt, mag sein, dürfte aber eher eine Frage des guten Stils sein als eine der richtigen Grammatik. Auch hier erscheint die Umformulierung schon deutlich angenehmer:

> Darauf, dass die Daten manipuliert wären, haben wir keine Hinweise.

Dass der Satzbau die Präposition verändern kann, halte ich in der deutschen Sprache für ausgeschlossen, kann aber leider keinen Nachweis hierfür bringen.

Comment: Ich bin dm Link gefolgt und habe nichts gesehen, dass Deine Meinung unterstützt.

Comment: @CarstenS Ich schon.

Comment: @CarstenS »es gibt nicht den geringsten Hinweis dafür, dass ein Verbrechen vorliegen könnte«, bei den Beispielen ganz unten.

Comment: @Jan, hatte ich übersehen, Danke. Dann gebe ich Magnus echt, nur dem Duden nicht ;)

Comment: Die Einträge in Duden und Pons sind m.E. irreführend. Zumindest zeigt eine Google-Suche, dass schon in dem einzigen genannten Beispielsatz ["...dafür, dass"](https://www.google.com/#q=%22es+gibt+nicht+den+geringsten+Hinweis+daf%C3%BCr,+dass%22+-duden+-pons&tbas=0) weitaus weniger gebräuchlich ist, als ["...darauf, dass"](https://www.google.com/#q=%22es+gibt+nicht+den+geringsten+Hinweis+darauf,+dass%22+-duden+-pons&tbas=0), zumindest wenn man wie in meinen verlinkten Suchanfragen alle Suchergebnisse aus Duden und Pons wegfiltert.

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Hinweis) gibt als Beispiel mit Präposition: "[2] Die Kratzer waren Hinweise **auf** einen Kampf".